Automatically assigning a choice to new Sharepoint Items
I have a list of customers that my organization needs to call. I have another column with a Choice list of team-members (Not a Person field but a Choice Field) that a manager will use to assign customer information to for calls. This is a very large list and I would like the team-member to be assigned when I upload customer data to the list rather than the manager having to manually assign. I'd like it to assign customers evenly, so that each agent gets roughly the same number of customers to call. Thanks!

These requirements sound like a Power Automate flow:

use flow trigger "when item is created"
build an array of people to be assigned, generate a random number and pick an item from array by that number
update item - assign that person as responsible

It is unclear what purpose your existing column Choice of team-members (not a person, but choice type serve. I advice to use columns and their types appropriate - not to confuse other people with "Why column with people is not People type? Jenny just married and changed surname - do I have to go and update field choice values? etc..". In other words - if you want to list people, use people picker type of column.

Thank you for your recommendation.
